# How to deal with missing data using `blavaan`?

Tags: r, stan, structural-equation-model

I am trying to run Bayesian SEM on my data using `bsem` in `blavaan`. However, it doesn't seem like it has arguments like `missing = "FIML"` as in the case of the `lavaan` package. What would be the best practice of dealing with missingness other than list-wise deletion?

This is the paragraph where the authors talk about handling missing data, but I am not sure how exactly I should actualize their recommendations:
"While it is often useful and desirable to directly model the missing values with the rest of the model (e.g., Merkle 2011; O’Muircheartaigh and Moustaki 1999), `blavaan` employs a "missing at random" approach to missing data that differs across JAGS and Stan. In JAGS, one can include NA values in the data, and JAGS will sample these missing values as if they were extra model parameters. In contrast, Stan does not allow NA values in the data, so that one must handle the missing data manually. We utilize a "full information" likelihood (e.g., Wothke 2000) in our Stan models, which is the same likelihood that is used to handle missing data in lavaan and other software that performs maximum likelihood SEM estimation. This requires some **additional overhead in preparing the data to be sent to Stan**, because each case's observed values must be indexed, and cases are sorted by missing data pattern to speed up computations. Missing values could also be directly sampled ("imputed") in Stan, though this functionality is not currently available."

Answer (score 1):

This is a place where blavaan defaults are different than `lavaan` defaults. `blavaan` automatically employs a "full information" likelihood when there is missing data, and you don't have to add anything extra to the `bsem()` command.

Comment: @Vinicius: I don't know why you edit my answer so that two instances of package names appear as code, while a third instance is still plaintext. If anything, I would think that package names should be in italics instead of code.